# php print out array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I have an array and can't really narrow down the right way to print everything out.

Array:

```
$month = Array(
    "1" => "January",
    "2" => "February",
    "3" => "March",
    "4" => "April",
    "5" => "May",
    "6" => "June",
    "7" => "July",
    "8" => "August",
    "9" => "September",
    "10" => "October",
    "11" => "November",
    "12" => "December"
);
```

What I Tried:

```
function monthList() {
    require "config.php";
        echo '<select name="month" title="Choose A Month">';
    foreach ($month as $i => $value) {
        echo '<option value="'.the_month_#_here.'">'.$month[$i].'</option>';
    }
        echo '</select>';
}
```

Which works fine for pulling out the name but how would i pull out the number associated with it in the array? Thats what I need as the `option value`.

Comment: The number is `$i` from your `foreach` loop.

Comment: @rackemup420 And don't use `$month[$i]`. The point of the `foreach` loop is that you assigned each iteration to `$value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function monthList() {
    require "config.php";
        echo '<select name="month" title="Choose A Month">';
    foreach ($month as $i => $value) {
        echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$value.'</option>';
    }
        echo '</select>';
}
```

Comment: Use `$value` in the foreach loop, not `$month[$i]`.

Comment: @Michael, that is much better form, yes, but either should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$value.'</option>';
```

instead of

```
echo '<option value="'.the_month_#_here.'">'.$month[$i].'</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Hope this helps :).

```
   function monthList() {
        require "config.php";
            echo '<select name="month" title="Choose A Month">';
        foreach ($month as $i => $value) {
            echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$value.'</option>';
        }
            echo '</select>';
    }
```

Best of luck.